# gradle timestamped snapshot dependency resolution failure

Tags: dependencies, gradle, snapshot

Migrating a Maven to a Gradle build I've encountered a problem with timestamped snapshot dependencies. The resolution of the following dependency against my local repository (mavenLocal()) fails:

runtime 'org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-jnlp-servlet:1.0-beta-4-20131101.151755-1'

(I know, it's not advisable to depend on snapshots, and its probably less advisable to depend on timestamped snapshots.)

Given the dependency above Gradle looks for:

C:\Users\p12345\.m2\repository/org/codehaus/mojo/webstart-jnlp-servlet/1.0-beta-4-20131101.151755-1/webstart-jnlp-servlet-1.0-beta-4-20131101.151755-1.jar

whereas, I think, Gradle should look for:

C:\Users\p12345\.m2\repository/org/codehaus/mojo/webstart-jnlp-servlet /1.0-beta-4-SNAPSHOT/webstart-jnlp-servlet-1.0-beta-4-20131101.151755-1.jar.

Note the folder name snafu: Gradle looks for ..\1.0-beta-4-20131101.151755-1\.., whereas Maven looks for the dependency in ..\1.0-beta-4-SNAPSHOT\.... And Maven does find the dependency there.

It looks as if Gradle dependency resolution isn't compatible here with Maven's. Am I missing something, or is this an issue? (I'm using Gradle 1.8)

Answer (score 1):

It's a known limitation, and unfortunately, I'm not aware of a workaround.